# In a jquery ajax call with in a .then promise, should async be true or false?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I have ajax request that I want a promise to wait for (using .then). In the ajax request (that I want my code to wait for) what should async be set to?

If I have async: false then my promise seems to work fine but all other events are blocked while the script waits for the ajax request to return.

If I have async: true then my promise seems to not wait for the ajax to return

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: The `async` option of `$.ajax` should never be set to `false` for the blocking reason you mention. Show us the outline of the code you are having problems with. Your solution will not be related to using `async: false/true` at all. Yes you are missing something but we need to see your code to sort out what it is

Comment: Thank you. Could the issue be the way the promises are called? - they were like this do_ajax().then(do_thing_after(vars) ) - is that not quite right? I have seen this do_ajax().then( function() { do_thing_after(vars); } ) is the first one wrong and the second correct?

Comment: Second looks right but assumes that you return the ajax promise in the first function

Comment: Thank you. How would I return the ajax promise in the first function please? Is it just a matter of putting return $.ajax({ ...?

Comment: Yes regarding the `return`